# Vim highlights word "mktemp" in Bash script

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm programming Bash scripts using Vim in Ubuntu 16.04 (on Windows Subsystem for Linux).

The filename ends in `.sh` and the first line of the file is

```
#!/bin/bash
```

When I wrote this command

```
rm -rf /tmp/*
   ~~~
```

The "word" `-rf` is shown in red (I use underlying tildes to point it out). I guess it's because Vim detected that `-rm` is a dangerous option when supplied to `rm`.

Later I wrote this:

```
tmpDir=$(mktemp "tmp-XXXXXX")
          ~~~~~~
```

and Vim confusingly marked `mktemp` as red.

[image]

Why is that? Can I stop Vim from marking this very word as red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `-rf` is shown in red because it is recognized as an option, and red is the default color for the `shOption` syntax group.

`mktemp` is colored red because it is recognized as a `shCommandSub`. Bash commands will typically be colored differently here. You should notice that most things written in `$(...)` will be colored red, except strings, bash commands, and probably some more things.

You can see the syntax group(s) of the word under the cursor with this:

```
:echo reverse(map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")'))
```